# Replacing Stings, Index (-1) value must be greater or equal to zero.?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm getting the following error in my app's script when replacing strings in a `template` file to generate reports.

```
Index (-1) value must be greater or equal to zero.
```

The function is listed bellow.

```
/**
* Search a String in the document and replaces it with the generated newString, and sets it Bold
*/
function replaceString(doc, String, newString) {

  var ps = doc.getParagraphs();
  for(var i=0; i<ps.length; i++) {
    var p = ps[i];
    var text = p.getText();
    //var text = p.editAsText();

    if(text.indexOf(String) >= 0) {
      //look if the String is present in the current paragraph
      //p.editAsText().setFontFamily(b, c, DocumentApp.FontFamily.COMIC_SANS_MS);
      p.editAsText().replaceText(String, newString);

      // we calculte the length of the string to modify, making sure that is trated like a string and not another ind of object.
      var newStringLength = newString.toString().length;

      // if a string has been replaced with a NON empty space, it sets the new string to Bold,
      Logger.log([newString,newStringLength]);
      if (newStringLength > 0) {
        // re-populate the text variable with the updated content of the paragraph
        text = p.getText();
        Logger.log(text);
        p.editAsText().setBold(text.indexOf(newString), text.indexOf(newString) + newStringLength - 1, true);
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

When it errors out

```
[newString,newStringLength] = [ The Rev Levels are at ZGS 003 on the electric quality standard. The part has a current change to ZGS 005!,108]
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance, 
Michael

Comment: What line gives the error?  Is that the error msg from the Execution Transcript?

Comment: Sandy,  The error appears at line 'p.editAsText().setBold(text.indexOf(newString), text.indexOf(newString) + newStringLength - 1, true);'

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling the case where the string isnt there. Thus indexOf returns -1 and you use that. Also dont use reserved words like String for variable names.